# Woocommerce Custom Order Status Does Not Show

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have been trying to add custom order status **Shipped** in woocommerce.

here is the code

```
function add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

        $new_order_statuses = array();

        // add new order status before processing
        foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
            $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
            if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
                $new_order_statuses['wc-order-shipped'] = __('Shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }

        return $new_order_statuses;


    }
```

```
  function register_shipped_status() {


            register_post_status( 'wc-order-shipped', array(
                'label'                     => _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
                'public'                    => true,
                'exclude_from_search'       => false,
                'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
                'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
                'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
            ) );


    }
```

```
add_action( 'init', array( $plugin_admin_meta_box, 'register_shipped_status') );

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', array( $plugin_admin_meta_box, 'add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses') );
```

The Shipping status is shown everywhere in woocommerce and it is working perfectly

[image]

Whenever i change the status of an order to shipped the order is updated successfully

***Now the problem is that shipped orders are not showing in orders table***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following works to add a functional custom order status in a custom plugin:

```
// Register new custom order status
function register_shipped_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-order-shipped', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Add new custom order status to list of WC Order statuses
function add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-order-shipped'] = _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status to admin order list bulk actions dropdown
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $new_actions = array();

    // Add new custom order status after processing
    foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
        $new_actions[$key] = $action;
        if ('mark_processing' === $key) {
            $new_actions['mark_order-shipped'] = __( 'Mark Shipped', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $new_actions;
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shipped_status' );
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Or for plugins** with a Class (and a constructor), remove:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_shipped_status' );
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
```

And add to the constructor the following:

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'register_shipped_status') );
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', array($this, 'add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses') );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', array($this, 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order'), 20, 1 );
```

[image]

Comment: You're right ! Im sorry. Well i just tried your code and it removed all the original woocommerce order statuses. I think the problem is with the add_action/add_filter args but im not sure about how to solve that.

I put your code in a code snippet

Comment: I tried to replace your last 3 lines by ```add_action( 'init', 'register_shipped_status' );
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shippped_to_order_statuses');
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );``` the everything is showing fine but when i click on `Mark Shipped` it's not working

Comment: @Arès Just tested my updated code on last WooCommerce version under storefront theme and it works on bulk custom status change too. So may be there is something else that is making trouble in your case…

Comment: Yup, it works now, i just needed to change 2-3 things to fit with my theme. Thank you !